# Use two foreign key in table with 'on delete cascade'

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE Comments(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(0,1),
    TEXT NOT NULL,
    Date Date NOT NULL ,
    Point INT NOT NULL DEFAULT(0), 
    ID_User INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Users(Id) ON DELETE CASCADE NOT NULL,
    ID_Post INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Posts(Id)  NOT NULL
)
```

When I delete User from Users table it show me error that Comments table has
other Reference Key. What i have to do ?

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK__Comments__ID_Pos__76969D2E". The conflict occurred in database "Facebook", table "dbo.Comments", column 'ID_Post'.

Comment: Can you add the exact error message to your question, please.

Comment: My guess is that you have cascading on deleting to your table `Posts` from `Users`, but (as your DDL shows above) not on `Comments` from `Posts`. As a result, when you delete a User, it cascades to `Posts` and tries to delete those. Upon doing so, however, as there is no cascade to comments (which are made by users that aren't the OP) would be left "orphaned", and hence the error.

Comment: A fix would be to a `ON DELETE CASCADE` to the other FK as well.

Comment: Do you know what is my general problem? When i delete User from Users table happening problem with ID_Post. If i can remove ID_Post like ID_User it problem will be solved. If User deleted from Users table the user's posts,comments have to delete at the same time

Comment: Yes, therefore add `ON DELETE CASCADE` to both of your foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete a user record, you need to delete the records in the foreign key tables.

In this case, you need to delete records in `Comments` table.

```
DELETE from dbo.Commnts
Where ID_User = "userid"
```

Then, you can remove the user record from `Users` table

Answer (score 0):

I did some work on this, there is no error in the foreign keys you referenced here. you may probably have reference to comment id in some other tables.

this is what I tried

```
CREATE TABLE Users(
Id int primary key

)

CREATE TABLE posts(
Id int primary key
)

insert into Users values(1);
insert into Users values(2);

insert into posts values(3);
insert into posts values(4);


CREATE TABLE Comments(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(0,1),
    ID_User INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Users(Id) ON DELETE CASCADE NOT NULL,
    ID_Post INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Posts(Id)  NOT NULL
)

insert into Comments values(1,3);
insert into Comments values(2,4);

DELETE 
FROM Users
WHERE id = 1 --this works fine
```